# How to deal with a single biomarker measurement that is time dependent

Tags: distributions, correlation, survival, interaction

**Information:**
We measured about 50 biomarkers derived from 100 patients. There is only one time point at which the sample is collected. The samples were stored in the refrigerator until we analysed them all at once.
But, due to it being a rather large cohort, and this being a pilot with selected matches, time from the moment of sample collection (blood drawn) until analysis varies from 10 years to 4 years.

**Problem:**
I made scatterplots for all biomarkers (y = value, x = studynumber (and thus time sample collected) and found that the value of biomarkers decreases with increasing studynumbers. To clarify this: older samples scored higher values on average, lower samples scored lower. Case & controls are evenly distributed. This is true for almost all 50 markers.
Methods have not changed over time. It's probably not due to different/better patient characteristics over time.

**Goal:**
Our goal is to find a biomarker with good predictive value of a certain event over time. I'll use a cox survival model for this and perhaps use a method like R's surv_cutpoint (using maxstat (correlations between all two-sample rank statistics)) to dichotomize the values.

**Question:**
Is there a way to deal with the problem? And perhaps more importantly, should I correct for a decline in value of a single measurement?

Thank you very much.